# Is "serialisation without duplication" possible in c++0x?

Tags: serialization, compile-time, c++11

One of the big uses of code generation in c++ is to support message serialisation.  Typically, you want to support specifying message contents and layout in the same step and produce code for that message type that can give you objects capable of being serialised to/from communication streams.  In the past, this has usually resulted in code that looks like:

```
class MyMessage : public SerialisableObject
{
  // message members
  int myNumber_;
  std::string myString_;
  std::vector<MyOtherSerialisableObject> aBunchOfThingsIWantToSerialise_;

public:
  // ctor, dtor, accesors, mutators, then:

  virtual void Serialise(SerialisationStream & stream)
  {
    stream & myNumber_;
    stream & myString_;
    stream & aBunchOfThingsIWantToSerialise_;
  }
};
```

The problem with using this kind of design is that violates an important rule of good architecture: you should not have to specify the intent of a design twice.  Duplication of intent, like duplicated code and other common development duplication, leaves room for one place in the code to become divergent with the other, causing errors.

In the above, the duplication is the list of members.  Potential errors include adding a member to the class but forgetting to add it to the serialisation list, serialising a member twice (possibly by not using the same order as the member declaration or possibly due to a misspelling of a similar member, among other ways), or serialising something that is not a member (which might produce a compiler error, unless name lookup finds something at a different scope than the object that matches lookup rules).  That kind of mistake is the same reason we no longer try to match every heap allocation with a delete (instead using smart pointers) or ever file open with a close (using RAII ctor//dtor mechanisms) - we don't want to have to match up our intent in multiple places because there are times we - or another engineer less familiar with the intent - make mistakes.

Generally, therefore, this has been one of the things that code generation could take care of.  You might create a file MyMessage.cg to specify both layout and members in one step

```
serialisable MyMessage
{
  int myNumber_;
  std::string myString_;
  std::vector<MyOtherSerialisableObject> aBunchOfThingsIWantToSerialise_;
};
```

that would be run through a code generation utility and produce the code.

I was wondering if it was possible yet to do this in c++0x without external code generation.  Are there any new language mechanisms that make it possible to specify a class as serialisable once, and the names and layout of it's members are used to layout the message during serialisation?

To be clear, I know that there are tricks with boost tuples and fusion that can come close to this kind of behavior even in the pre-c++0x language.  Those usages, though, being based on indexing into the tuple rather than by-member-name access, have all been brittle to changing the layout, as other places in the code that access the messages would then also need to be reordered.  Some kind of by-member-name access is necessary to not have to duplicate the layout specification in places in the code that use the messages.

Also, I know it might be nice to take this up to the next level and ask for specifying when some of the members *shouldn't* be serialised.  Other languages that offer serialisation built in often offer some kind of attribute to do this, so
    int myNonSerialisedNumber_ [[noserialise]];
might seem natural.  However, I personally think it is bad design to have serialisable objects where everything is not serialised, since the lifetime of messages is in the transport to/from the communications layer, separate from other data lifetimes.  Also, you could have an object which has a purely serialisable as on of it's members, so such functionality doesn't by anything the language doesn't already offer.

Is this possible?  Or did the standards committee leave out this kind of introspective capability?  I don't need it to look like the code gen file above - any simple method for compiletime specification of layout and members in a single step would solve this common problem.

Comment: I think for this to work, C++ would need some for of "*compile time* reflection". Googling for this leads to some interesting articles:  [check out Boost](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/wiki/LibrariesUnderConstruction#ReflectiveProgramming)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is both possible and practical in C++11 – in fact it was possible back in C++03, the syntax was just a little too unwieldy.  I wrote a small library based around the same idea - see the following:

[www.github.com/molw5/framework](http://www.github.com/molw5/framework)

Sample syntax:

```
class Object : serializable <Object,
    value <NAME(“Field 1”), int>,
    value <NAME(“Field 2”), float>,
    value <NAME(“Field 3”), double>>
{
};
```

Most of the underlying code could be reproduced, in principal, in C++03 – some of the implementation details without variadic templates would have been...tricky, but I believe it would have been possible to recover the core functionality.  What you could not reproduce in C++03 was the NAME macro above and the syntax relies fairly heavily on it.  The macro provides the machinery necessary to generate a unique typename from a string, that is the following:

```
NAME(“Field 1”)
```

expands to

```
 type_string <'F', 'i', 'e', 'l', 'd', ' ', '1'>
```

through the use of some common macros and constexpr (for character extraction).  Back in C++03 something similar to the type_string above would need to be entered manually.

Comment: Thank you very much for this!  I think the string trick was the final problem I was trying to understand, as it is necessary to do a lookup on the identifier at translationtime to provide compiler errors, but can't have string literals as template parameters directly.  After looking at your framework examples (particularly the access timings), I see this does appear to do everything needed.  The constexpr expansion of literals does seem like it's necessary for usability, but typelist compare has certainly been around earlier.  Thank you very much with this!

Answer (score 1):

C++, of any form, supports neither introspection nor reflection (to the extent that they are different).

One nice thing about doing serialization manually (ie: without introspection or reflection) is that you can provide object *versioning*. You can support older forms of the serialization, and simply create reasonable defaults for the data that wasn't in the old versions. Or if a new version removes some data, you can simply serialize and discard it.

It seems to me that what you need is Boost.Serialization.

Comment: I have found over the years that object versioning is a chimera that causes bad design.  Every object that must be serialised should have a message identifier.  This is used in dispatch on input and used by the callee in output.  I've seen many protocols that use some structure like a major, minor, and version number, but in design, that all needs to be packaged up in a tuple used for dispatch.  So any version number is just a separate identifier for a separate message object, and it's always best to handle them separately.  If they're separate - make them different objects.

Comment: I'm not asking for full introspection or reflection, nor is it needed here.  If I have the ability to build my classes so that I give that information during their structuring, then I get what is needed.  For instance, I mentioned boost tuple/fusion as a method for building that combines the two.  Unfortunately, it fails because you have to repeat layout at use.  I could do a map<string, string> as my members, but then I need to repeat type info upon retrieval.  Basically, I need a container of heterogenous types indexable by a translationtime token.

Comment: @ex0du5: How do you have to repeat the layout of a tuple "at use"? That's what typedefs are for.

Comment: I mean something like "int myNumber(get<3>(myTuple));".  The 3 is an index into the tuple, and would need to be changed if during development I needed to insert a new second element, shifting everything down.  If I listed out the indexes with things like "int const myNumberIndex(10);" and used "int myNumber(get<myNumberIndex>(myTuple));", then I am just moving the place I am duplicating the layout to that list, which would need changing every time I updated the layout.  I don't know of a way typedef would prevent that duplication either.  What do you have in mind?

Comment: @ex0du5: If you insert a new second element, then you have changed the serialization. The version of the object has changed; it no longer matches the previous format. It isn't the same object it used to be. You said that this was a bad idea, that you should use a different object in that case. So switch to using a different object if you change the object's internals.

Comment: @ex0du5: It seems to me that you want something C++ can't do. C++ does not allow you to iterate over a typed sequence. You can use tuples, but you have swapped out member names for integers to use with `get`. Everything in C++ can only be accessed by name, and you will _have_ to repeat that name whenever you access that thing. Whether that name is a member field of a struct, an integer offset into a tuple, or whatever, everything is named. And you must use the name to talk to it.

Comment: The point about versioning has to do with deployment, not development.  Very often when developing a new communication protocol, either working with a device team to put a new USB product out or working with a server team to build a new protocol or simply building up a new file format to save the product, the message structure changes some.  You are not changing version because you are still only using that one message.  Once deployed, you usually have to support the old message indefinitely.  So, you usually want to support revisions without versioning.

Comment: I guess you may be right about it not being able to do it yet.  c++ does allow iterating over types, though, as the MPL sequences show.  And there are even "type maps" that map one type to another, so it is very close to being possible with type tags that you can do translationtime lookup.  Going that way seems to require at least one point where you need to do something twice with types, adding in the duplication.  I was hoping with the new type deduction capabilities of c++0x and some constexpr stuff, it might be possible to finally avoid code gen.  I accept your answer.